# Setup xuggler as applet

Tags: java, applet, xuggler

How to setup Xuggler as applet?

I created a small application using xuggler (5.4) when I modify it to run as applet it doesn't work.

Can someone please advise me what possible way can I setup so as to meet my following requirement?

1. I am having a webpage, when user click start(button on page) it should launch application.
2. Since file size is little big(because of xuggler 5.4, which supports all os leading to bigger size), i don't want my users to download every time.

Few possible work around I can think of are -

1. Load xuggler native library after checking the OS of user, but i don't know how to do that
2. Ask users to download application and call the same from another java applet by passing parameters, now again i don't know ho to do that.

Comment: The last time I checked, the authors of Xuggler claimed it was not usable in applets or JWS apps. because that form of launch could not guarantee the load order of natives.

Comment: did you make it work ?